# actionbar with tabs : fragment not using

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-view

I want to use tabs in action bar. For simplicity there is only 1 tab now. Problem is that no view / ui is visible.

Oncreate functn of activity that contains tabs -

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tabs = new Vector<ActionBar.Tab>();
    ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.Tab accountsTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Accounts");
    Fragment accountsFragment = new AccountsFragment();
    accountsTab.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(accountsFragment));
    actionbar.addTab(accountsTab);
    tabs.add(accountsTab);
}
```

The oncreateview of fragment AccountsFragment that extends Fragment (android.app.Fragment) :

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
    textView.setText("SimpleFragmentText");
    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    textView.setTextSize(20);
    return textView;
}
```

Finally the Tab listener is as follows :

```
 public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    if(fragment!=null) {
        fragmentTransaction.add(fragment,"accounts");
        fragmentTransaction.show(fragment);
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    if(fragment!=null) {
        fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment);
    }
}
```

All other functions are not over-ridden. Nothing displays excep the tab with heading "Accounts".

My main.xml contains linear layout.

Comment: YOu have not added any text to the text view. textView.setText("Testing tabs");

Comment: that is there : textView.setText("SimpleFragmentText");

Comment: nope. xml based UI is not compulsory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tabs = new Vector<ActionBar.Tab>();
        ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
        actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.Tab accountsTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Accounts");
        accountsTab.setTabListener(new MyTabListener());
        actionbar.addTab(accountsTab);
        tabs.add(accountsTab);
    }

    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        if(fragment!=null) {
           AccountsFragment frag = new AccountsFragment();
           fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, frag);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        if(fragment!=null) {
            fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment);
        }
    }
```

Comment: does not work... moreover it might be ok for debugging purpose but otherwise, tablistener in above case is not reusable..

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your onTabSelected -

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // Check if the fragment is already initialized
            if (mFragment == null) {
                // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
                mFragment = (Fragment) Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
                ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
            } else {
                // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
                ft.attach(mFragment);
            }
        }
```